# Greek text english references

Tags: bibtex, greek, english

I am trying to figure out how it could work to write in greek text and have english references. I've tried a lot of what I found in my search, but nothing is working properly for me, at least.

What I have is below

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english,greek,twoside]{hua}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{makeidx}
%\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[greek]{babel}
%\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\addto\captionsgreek{%
  \renewcommand{\indexname}{Ευρετήριο όρων}%
}
\makeindex

% 1.5 spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}

% latin text (and greek text)
\newcommand{\tl}[1]{\textlatin{#1}}
\newcommand{\tg}[1]{\textgreek{#1}}
\newcommand{\lat} {\latintext} 
\newcommand{\gre}{\greektext}

\begin{document}
\lat{\bibliography{references}}
\end{document}
```

Whatever you see commented on usepackage was my tries independently or combined. Please if you have any idea, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this works for you:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{\selectlanguage{british}}
```

I don't have `hua.cls`, it seems. But, for example:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{aa,
  author =     {Me and Myself and I},
  title =      {My Article},
  journal =    {My Journal},
  year =       {2016},
  number =     1,
  volume =     1,
  pages =      {1-20},
}

@article{bb,
  author =     {Us and Them},
  title =      {Our Article},
  journal =    {Our Journal},
  year =       {1996},
  number =     2,
  volume =     2,
  pages =      {1-20},
}
\end{filecontents}
%\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english,greek,twoside]{hua}
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{makeidx}
%\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% <-- normally, I'd load this earlier, but it defines \AtBeginEnvironment...
\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{\selectlanguage{british}}
\addto\captionsgreek{%
  \renewcommand{\indexname}{Ευρετήριο όρων}%
}
\makeindex

% 1.5 spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}

% latin text (and greek text)
\newcommand{\tl}[1]{\textlatin{#1}}
\newcommand{\tg}[1]{\textgreek{#1}}
\newcommand{\lat} {\latintext}
\newcommand{\gre}{\greektext}

\begin{document}

\tg{Ευρετήριο όρων}
\gre Ευρετήριο όρων

\cite{aa,bb}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add support for English:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{uthor2025,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2025,
}
\end{filecontents*}

%\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english,greek,twoside]{hua}
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\addto\captionsgreek{%
  \renewcommand{\indexname}{Ευρετήριο όρων}%
  \renewcommand{\bibname}{\textgreek{Βιβλιογραφία}}%
}
\makeindex

% 1.5 spacing
\linespread{1.2}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

% latin text (and greek text)
\newcommand{\tl}[1]{\textlatin{#1}}
\newcommand{\tg}[1]{\textgreek{#1}}
\newcommand{\lat} {\latintext} 
\newcommand{\gre}{\greektext}

\begin{document}

\cite{uthor2025}

Λορεμ ιπσθμ δολορ σιτ αμετ, σανcτθσ δελιcατα αδιπισcινγ περ τε, 
θταμθρ σενσιβθσ σεα ιν. Πθρτο ρεφερρεντθρ σιγνιφερθμqθε θτ νεc, 
cασε προβο εφφιcιενδι vισ ιδ, αν βρθτε ριδενσ vερεαρ ναμ. Ιδ ερρορ 
αετερνο περcιπιτθρ vισ, περ ατ εσσε ινσολενσ εξπετενδισ. Δθισ 
διcιτ ινιμιcθσ εαμ αν, νεμορε ομνιθμ σιτ εθ. Qθο cθ διαμ περcιπιτ 
αccθσαμθσ.

Ει προ vερο νοvθμ σενσεριτ, εαμ cομμθνε qθαεστιο σθαvιτατε εθ, εαμ 
vιδισσε εθριπιδισ θτ. Εθ ελεcτραμ σαλθτατθσ qθο, δθο αδ ταλε νθσqθαμ. 
Ει πρι προπριαε λαβοραμθσ, ηισ θτ jθστο ελιγενδι vολθπτθα. Vελ μαζιμ 
νοστερ ελεcτραμ νε, vιvενδθμ τορqθατοσ προ ιν. Εσσε vιδε σεα ει, ιν 
vελ μαιορθμ νομιναvι περcιπιτθρ.

\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{otherlanguage*}

\end{document}
```

Some notes.

- Avoid the `utf8x` option
- T2A is the encoding for Cyrillic
- `epstopdf` is automatically loaded
- `latexsym` is obsolete

I used the `book` class, not knowing about `hua`.

If you want the title of the bibliography chapter to be in English, use

```
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{otherlanguage}
```

I used `\jobname` together with `filecontents*` just to make the example self-contained. You'll use your `.bib` file.

[image]

Comment: your answer was very helpful